# Azure Webapp deployment failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I am developing an asp.net project which is deploying on the Azure web app using publish profile. Suddenly today the deployment is failed.

Got the following error:

*Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)*

I tried a couple of solutions but getting the same error.

1. Tried to deploy by turning off the firewall.
2. I also tried to add a new setting in the Azure web app -
   `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM:false`
3. Tried to deploy code from another machine.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Try browsing to XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net - see if you can access?   This https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues also contains some debuggig tips.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net. My azure site is also working fine. ie. XXX.azurewebsites.net

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. I manually update the files using FTP.